# Accessing link in email message using gmail api & Cypress

Tags: gmail-api, cypress

hope u all safe , 
i am doing e2e automated test by Cypress , and i have problem to access link in the received email (Gmail account)from a specific email address. So far using GMAIL api I am able to get the email id using Cy.task

1. testCase 1. : visit signup page and fill information .// Passed
2. testCase 2 : ensure that email has received by using gmail-tester library // Passed
3. testCase 3: **the problem is here** ===>> click on CTA `confirm ur email address` and it should direct me to confirmation page Or extract href then cy.visit(href)

[image]

```
**href**="http://post.spmailtechnol.com/f/a/mD0QS83FHCNqxzGZpDJgfg~~/AALxrAA~/RgRgYvyvP0T3aHR0cHM6Ly9uZXh0LWRldi50YWphd2FsLmNvbS9lbi91c2VyL3ZlcmlmeT90b2tlbj00ZjM5Y2I0ZC0yZjU2LTQxYmItOWFlNC0yMDFjN2Y3ZTAyM2UmcmVxdWVzdElkPWM2ZGNiOTEwLThkZWQtNDFhYy05ODQ0LWJjMTdlZWFmOTEyNyZ1dG1fc291cmNlPXRyYW5zYWN0aW9uYWwmdXRtX21lZGl1bT1lbWFpbCZ1dG1fY2FtcGFpZ249MjAyMDAzMzBfRU5fQ09NX1JFR0lTVFJBVElPTiZ1dG1fY29udGVudD1Cb2R5JnV0bV90ZXJtPUNUQVcDc3BjQgoAAC_JgV6KRz5mUh9lbHNoYWlraHRlc3RlbWFpbHMrMjBAZ21haWwuY29tWAQAAAAB" style="font-size:14px;color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none;border-radius:2px;padding:12px 0 12px 0;display:inline-block;border-top:1px solid #499df3;border:none;font-weight:bold;min-width:190px;text-align:center;background:#1dac08"
↵                                               target="_blank">Confirm email</a>
```

thanks in advance for ur reply & help , Thank you

Comment: Hello! So, I don't think clicking inside the gmail account is necessary. Every link sent when registering apparently has a token. What I would do is try to get from your API/backend that token for that email and add it to the link and visit it using cypress. This test would both test if the token generated properly and if the account registration could be finished.

Comment: Second, never link stuff like that publicly, you just showed with that link to your dev env ;)

Comment: Hi ! In which way are you using the Gmail API? Are you basically just trying to get a specific email message from the user inbox? Could you please share a sample code  where you are implementing this Gmail API call? (Please, do not include any sensitive data).

Answer (score 0):

if you need to click on `href` try this

```
cy.get('[href*="post.spmailtechnol.com"]').click()

or

cy.get('[target="_blank"]').click()
```

Comment: hii @evgnil,No such feature with gmail api , if u know idea share it with me 
for how to access link (href) in the received activation email ,  
https://gist.github.com/Elshaikh/fe372af19e3cac394449dc60859eb856
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJTap.png

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a raw body response (a string) you cannot use the cypress method unless you convert this strings into a DOM object so you have to get the link in this way if you have an email body as string:

```
const links = body.split("href=http://my.url.com");
var activation_link = links[0].match(/\bhttp?:\/\/\S+/);
activation_link= activation_link[0].replace('"','')
cy.visit(activation_link)
```